# Python not returning expected value when comparing files

Tags: python

I am trying to build this script to check if a file on a remote server contains a set suffix, IE .ok, .err, .log. I can't figure out why I am getting the return that I am
`"('\\\\THPNWSS5\\d$\\DA$Utils\\log\\networker', [], ['P3EWS.err']) nothing is equal`"
I know there is something wrong with my try statement but I can't see it.

```
    chkbkpstats = csv.reader(file('c://temp//networkerservers1.csv'))

    srvrs = []
    for row in chkbkpstats:
        srvrs.append({'Name' : row[0], 'Instance' : row[1]})

    for srvr in srvrs:
        srvrName = (srvr['Name'])
        srvrInst = (srvr['Instance'])
        w2k3chk = r'\\%s\d$\DA$Utils\log\networker' % srvrName
        w2k8chk = r'\\%s\c$\ProgramData\folder\DA$Utils\log\networker' % srvrName

        try:
            c = wmi.WMI(srvr['Name'])
        except:
            print 'Error connecting to %s to check OS version' % srvrName

        else:
            osVer = c.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0].Caption
            if '2003' in osVer:
                for file in os.walk(w2k3chk):
                    print file
                    try:
                        if srvrInst == srvrInst + ".log":
                            print 'The Backup for %s on %s still running' % (srvrInst, srvrName)
                        if srvrInst == (srvrInst + ".ok"):
                            print 'Completed Successfully'
                        if srvrInst == (srvrInst + ".err"):
                            print 'Backup failed'
                    except:
                        print 'nothing is equal'
                #print '%s is w2k3' % srvr['Name']
            elif '2008' in osVer:
                print '%s is w2k8' % srvr['Name']
```

Comment: Your "nothing is equal" except block will never trigger....

Comment: That is the only line that triggers.

Comment: You should avoid using bare `except:` clauses-- be specific about the exceptions you want to catch, like `AttributeError` or `IOError` or whatever.  Otherwise you could make a typo in a variable name, or have an extra comma somewhere, and the `NameError` or `TypeError` would be swallowed up, making debugging really hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @लंड has pointed out the most pressing error in your current code, his suggested fix, `file == (srcInst + ".log")` won't work either. That's because the `os.walk` function doesn't just return filenames. It returns a generator of three-tuples, each consisting of a directory, a list of subdirectories (which will also be walked) and a list of files. You need an extra loop to go over the individual files.

Something like this should work:

```
found = False
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(w2k3chk):
    for file in files:
        if file == srvrInst + ".log":
            found = True
            print 'The Backup for %s on %s still running' % (srvrInst, srvrName)
        elif file == (srvrInst + ".ok"):
            found = True
            print 'Completed Successfully'
        elif file == (srvrInst + ".err"):
            found = True
            print 'Backup failed'
if not found:
    print 'No file found'
```

If you're sure there should only ever be a single file in the folder you're searching, you can simplify that a bit:

```
try:
    folder, subfolders, files = next(os.walk(w2k3chk)):
    file = files[0]
    if file == srvrInst + ".log":
        print 'The Backup for %s on %s still running' % (srvrInst, srvrName)
    elif file == (srvrInst + ".ok"):
        print 'Completed Successfully'
    elif file == (srvrInst + ".err"):
        print 'Backup failed'
    else:
        print 'Unknown file found: %s' % (file)
except (StopIteration, IndexError): # exceptions if folder or file doesn't exist
    print 'No file found'
```

Comment: Wow. I was starting to read up on glob and fnmatch but this works. The first option works best for me as there might be more then 1 file in the dir. When I tried your code it still came back with _no file found_ When I did a print on **files** it gave me **['P3EWS.err']**. I am comparing that to P3EWS.xxx

Comment: Whoops, I missed fixing one of the `if` clauses. Just replace `srvrInst` on the left side of the last `elif` with `file`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This was what I was looking for. The first set is what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks for correctingme.

Answer (score 2):

This line has problem

```
 if srvrInst == file.srvrInst + ".log":
```

should be :-

```
if file == (srvrInst + ".log"):
```

file has no `srvrInst`.

**Update after edit:-**

How can you ever think this to be evaluated true:-

```
if srvrInst == (srvrInst + ".ok"):
```

Suppose `srvrInst="John"`

> **"John"=="John.ok"**

Can ever be true????

Comment: Yea, I removed it from the code here on the page. I forgot to make that edit when I copied and pasted from my notepad

Comment: Wow, I'm embarassed. No It can't.